# Boot Fedora 18 from Windows 7's bootloader

Tags: fedora, multi-boot, bcd, easybcd

In Ubuntu or previous releases of Fedora you could install grub to the linux partition and then add an entry to BCD (using EasyBCD or dd-ing partition's first 512 bytes to a file) to boot it. Now that there is no option to install grub to a partition ([ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=872826)), is there any way to boot Fedora 18 using Windows 7's bootloader?

Comment: Why would you even need the windows' boot loader? grub is far better...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Installed Fedora 18 along side existing Vista, letting it overwrite the MBR with Grub
2. Booted to Grub, selected Windows and booted to Vista
3. Used BCD to add Fedora 18 as a GRUB2 (**not** Grub!) boot
4. Used BCD to restore the MBR
5. Rebooted, and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get into fedora, you can manually install grub to a partition.  There are plenty of guides out there on how to do this and usually the first one on google is good enough.  After you install grub, it should auto-detect the windows 7 partition (you might have to put an entry into grub manually), after which you can boot into windows 7 and make the windows 7 bootloader the default bootloader.